# Qt TableView model setData() crashes application

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I am learning Qt and I am developing Minesweeper alike game now.

For displaying game board I am using QTableView with my custom model that extends `QAbstractTableModel`.

Displaying data from model works well. I have overloaded `QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role)` and all cells are displaying their "content" properly.

**Now I would like to handle game board clicks and pass any data to the model.**

I have overloaded setData() function:

```c++
bool MyModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) {
    qDebug("setData invoked");
    return false;
}
```

and handled  TableView clicks:

```c++
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QTableView *tableView = this->findChild<QTableView*>("tableView");
    tableView->setModel(new MyModel(tableView, DEFAULT_ROWS_NUM, DEFAULT_COLS_NUM));

    QObject::connect(tableView, &QAbstractItemView::clicked, [&](const QModelIndex &index) {
        qDebug(qUtf8Printable(QString("click: %1 %2").arg(index.row()).arg(index.column())));
        tableView->model()->setData(index, 'W'); // this line crashes application
    });
}
```

but `tableView->model()->setData()` causes application to crash:

```c++
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x0000000104bc9c67 QAbstractItemView::model() const + 7
1   studia.Minesweeper              0x0000000104939501 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::$_0::operator()(QModelIndex const&) const + 385 (mainwindow.cpp:13)
```

**Am I doing something wrong? Is this a good way to achieve changes in model on mouse click events?**

Comment: The problem maybe with your closure `[&]`. Replace this with `[tableView]`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much! @evgeny post it as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your closure `[&]`. Replace this with `[tableView]`.